# EXCEL 'IF STATEMENT' to allocate segmentation rules into a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having some difficulty allocating some segments to some data I have.

The data I have is a line by line sales ledger. I have already calculated the % discount in column AB and I want to add my categorizations into column BA that are outlined in columns BJ, so that I can then run an analysis of the number of units being sold with between 10% and 20% discount, 50% and 60% discount etc. Th end result should be like the 'end result picture.

You can see this in the image below.

I have tried a few different ways of doing this i.e. IF, nested IF etc, but I can't seem to get it right.

Is anyone able to assist?

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw0Tc.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are after a formula to calculate the number of items within a range that match your criteria? i.e. how many items are sold with between 0 and 10% discount etc...

Assuming that is the solution you are after you would use the COUNTIF or COUNTIFS functions depending on the version of excel you are using.
Assuming you are using a recent version of excel something like:
=COUNTIFS($AB$2:$AB$10,">=10", AB2:AB10,"<=20") 
otherwise 
=COUNTIF($AB$2:$AB$10, ">=10") - COUNTIF(AB2:AB10, ">20")

If that is not what you are trying to achieve please clarify the result you want from the formula.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for this. I am looking to band the discount percentages together. So if the discount given to a client is between 11 and 19% i am looking for an if statement which will then pull through  10%>Discount Given≤ 20%

Comment: i figured it out actually -

Comment: the formula i came up with was "=IF(AB29<=BG29,"No Discount Given",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$2,AB29<$BH$2),"0%>Discount Given≤ 10%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$3,AB29<$BH$3),"10.01%>Discount Given≤ 20%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$4,AB29<$BH$4),"20.01%>Discount Given≤ 30%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$5,AB29<$BH$5),"30.01%>Discount Given≤ 40%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$6,AB29<$BH$6),"40.01%>Discount Given≤ 50%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$7,AB29<$BH$7),"50.01%>Discount Given≤ 60%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$8,AB29<$BH$8),"60.01%>Discount Given≤ 70%",IF(AND(AB29>$BG$9,AB29<$BH$9),"70.01%>Discount Given≤ 80%" .....